# searchMetadataOnDemand reportviewer setting - how to verify reduced metadata returned?

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am getting a strange error when users are selecting parameters on a report that result in several 1000 records being returned (which is what they want), and its for a limited set of users.
This url
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/json-length-is-too-large-net-core
seems to indicate that less metadata will be returned when set.  How/where can I see this metadata at runtime, either while running locally in visual studio or in the browser?  I have tested it and it seems to work, but how can I verify this reduced volume of metadata?

Answer (score 1):

You may check the report HTML in the browser DevTools > Elements for the attribute 'data-search-id'. The meta information related to the [Search functionality of the Telerik HTML5 Report Viewer](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/embedding-reports/display-reports-in-applications/web-application/search) consists of this additional attribute added to the searchable components.

If you render the report in a viewer with 'searchMetadataOnDemand' set to 'False' (default), the report is rendered with these additional attributes, and when the user clicks the 'Search' button, the viewer performs a single [Search in a Document](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/embedding-reports/host-the-report-engine-remotely/rest-api-reference/documents-api/search-in-a-document) request that returns all data-search-id's that contain the searched text.

When 'searchMetadataOnDemand' is 'True', the report is rendered initially without the 'data-search-id' attributes. If the user clicks on 'Search', the report is generated once again completely to add all 'data-search-id' attributes, and then the viewer performs the 'Search in a Document' request.